# How can I get network speed in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows, mobile, networking, performance

when i access webservice,How can I get windows Mobile Application's network speed?

Comment: Which network? A typical windows mobile device can have several configured networks.

Comment: Thank you for your attention!My windows mobile application to access webservice,I want get the  instant speed.

Answer (score 0):

Ppen CMD (Command Promt) and do the following:

Execute this on one PC/Windows mobile device

```
iperf -c 192.168.0.100 example IP address client side
```

Execute this on the other PC/Windows mobile device

```
iperf -s server side
```

Here is also a ported version: http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~sakogan/iperf/